# Removing time series outliers in R with tsclean() - adjusting the sensibility to outliers

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, forecast

I have a time series object in R that contains data from sensors that measure bike traffic patterns.
I would like to remove outliers that represent measurment errors.
The measurment errors are easily identified with visual inspection.
The data has both annual and weekly seasonality, which seems to confound the process used in the tsclean() function from the forecast package, which is designed for this task.

I do not want to do this manually, because I will be automating the process for about 30 time series objects.

How can I adjust the tsclean() function so it is less sensitive to weekly cycles?

Please help! Thanks.

I am using the following code to remove outliers and plot the results for visual inspection.
I apologize, the ts object is way to large to generate an example here.

**1. No transformation**

```
library(forecast)

no_outlier <-  tsclean(ts_Rachel_HoteldeVille, lambda = NULL)
plot(ts_Rachel_HoteldeVille, col='black', lwd=2)
lines(no_outlier, col = "red", lwd=2)
title(main = "No transformation")
```

[image]

The outliers are represented by the black lines. There should only be about 9 data points being removed.
The cleaned data is in red.
It is too sensitive and is removing data points that represent normal weekly variation

**2. Box Cox applied**

```
no_outlier_boxcox <-  tsclean(ts_Rachel_HoteldeVille, lambda = "auto")
plot(ts_Rachel_HoteldeVille, col='black', lwd=2)
lines(no_outlier, col = "orange", lwd=2)
title(main = "Box Cox applied")
```

[image]

I also tryed with the Box-Cox transformation applied, which offers somewhat better results, but not perfect.
In this case, the orange lines represent the "cleaned" time series.
It is still cutting out certain non-outlier data points, but it actually kept an obvious outlier.

Comment: You say it’s easy to do “visually” but a lot of the black outlier data points are at the same level as the red ones.

Comment: The seven outliers are the datapoints at the top of those long black vertical lines on the top half of the chart. Non outliers is what clustered in those cycles at the bottom half of the chart. Black = original time series. Red = time series after tsoutliers() has removed what it percieves as outliers

Answer (score 1):

`tsclean()` fits an MSTL model to the time series, and then removes the seasonal component. Next it fits a "super smoother" to model the trend, which is removed from the seasonally adjusted data. Finally, it identifies outliers in the remainder series using the same threshold as "far-out" values in Tukey's original boxplot. See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tsoutliers/ for the details.

If it isn't working for your data, you can do something similar, but find a way of modelling the seasonality and/or trend that is better suited to your application. The key idea is to model the signal in some way, remove it, and find the outliers in what's left.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

I now understand that my problem is that I have a ts object that does not take into account both patterns in my data.
To create a msts object that has both weekly pattern an annual pattern, and contains 10 years of data, would this be the correct specification?

msts_object <- msts(df$variable, start = c(start_year, start_month, start_day), seasonal.periods =c(7,365.25))

Comment: Nearly. The start argument must be specified as either a single number (in years), or as a vector of two numbers (year, day_of_year).

Comment: Ok thanks!

Unfortunately, tsclean is still to sensitive. 
I will look into finding something similar.

I appreciate your help though, it has definitely steered me in the right direction.